# after upgrade to 2.7 ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.exceptions.Reporter when run test

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I try to set up junit, mokito and powermock together but when I ran a test I get ClassNotFoundException :(

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.22"

testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2'
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'

testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.6'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.6'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.6'`
```

I also tried adding cglib by adding:

```
testCompile 'cglib:cglib:3.1'
testCompile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1'
```

but without of lack.

could any one share working configuration or point me out what is wrong.

My stacktrace when I ran a test:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:251)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.getInstanceForClassLoader(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:41)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.create(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:35)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.getMockingFrameworkReporter(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:140)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:119)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.exceptions.Reporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's what worked for me:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.0'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.0'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.7.0'
```

using Mockito2 fixed the problem for me.

Comment: There is no mockito-core:2.8.0 available. Can you post the correct version?

Comment: I was able to get it working with this combination:  
`testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` . 
`testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.9.0'` . 
`testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2'` 
`testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0'` . 
 `testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.0'` .

Comment: use `testImplementation` instead of `testCompile` as it has been deprecated

Answer (score 64):

**PowerMock 1.6** isn't compatible with **Mockito 2.7** (take a look at https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions)

You should use **PowerMock 1.7.0RC2** (or **1.7.0RC3** if **1.7.0RC2** doesn't work), and also use **powermock-api-mockito2** instead of **powermock-api-mockito**.

Comment: Using powermock-api-mockito2 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Kotlin `1.2.61`/mockito `2.15` and powermock `1.7.0RC2` **DID NOT** work me. The set of dependencies that did the trick for me is:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.15.0"
    testImplementation "io.kotlintest:kotlintest:2.0.7"
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.0-beta.5'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.0-beta.5'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use PowerMock 1.7.+ (it's always better to use the last version), and also use powermock-api-**mockito2** instead of powermock-api-mockito.

```
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:${versions.powermock}"
```

Comment: Changing to powermock-api-mockito2 seemed to work for me. Thanks!