# NoClassDefFoundError - org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter when Using Mockito and PowerMock

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to add Powermock to my application that uses Mockito.
This is what I currently have in my gradle build:

```
 compile("junit:junit:4.12"){force = true}
  compile("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:1.7.0")     
  compile("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0")
  compile("org.powermock:powermock-api-support:1.7.0")
  compile("org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.0")
  compile("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0")
  compile("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:1.7.0")
  compile("org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.7.0")
  compile("org.javassist:javassist:3.12.0.GA")
  compile("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9")
```

This is the test file that I have so far...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(XMLTransaction.class)
public class CloseSummaryOrCloseTrailerResponseTest {

     public final static String URL="WL_APPSERVER";
     private XMLTransaction xmlTransaction; 

    @Before
    public void initMocks() throws Exception {
        xmlTransaction = PowerMockito.spy(new XMLTransaction(URL));
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(xmlTransaction, "initialize");    
    }

    @Test
    public void whenCloseSummaryResponseNoErrorExpectCorrectXmlMsgProduced ()
    {
        ...test code here
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at
>   org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
>     at
>   org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:251)
>     at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)

The **Reporter** class should be contained in mockito-core.
What additional jars do I need?
I reviewed the compatiability of Mockito and Powermock using this site:
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions

But it seems I am missing some other jar.

**UPDATE**
Checked that answer but it did not solve my problem.
I changed

```
compile("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0")
```

to

```
compile("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2")
```

Now I get a different error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension API internal error:
>   org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could
>   not be located in classpath.  at
>   org.powermock.reflect.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkHelper.register(ProxyFrameworkHelper.java:35)

What jar does this need?

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940857/after-upgrade-to-2-7-classnotfoundexception-org-mockito-exceptions-reporter-whe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [after upgrade to 2.7 ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.exceptions.Reporter when run test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940857/after-upgrade-to-2-7-classnotfoundexception-org-mockito-exceptions-reporter-whe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me...was that I deleted all of powermock jars in my lib folder and then used the above gradle code and rebuilt.
I was able to run the test.

Comment: It's not working for me. is there any other way of work around for this. I'm using maven and spring boot